# Display Port monitor not detected Ubuntu 18.04 - VGA ok - Intel Ivybridge Mobile GC

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor

VGA monitor running fine.  Got a second monitor to run off the displayPort on the docking station.. Cable is a displayport to DVI adapter.  Ubuntu just doesn't detect the second monitor.

Machine is HP Ultrabook with Intel® Core™ i5-3427U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4

GC is Intel® Ivybridge Mobile

Running 64-Bit

Can anyone help me?